# Problema con separador de listas cambiando de entorno

Tags: c#, lista, conversión-de-tipos

estoy teniendo el siguiente inconveniente con el separador de listas que viene definido según cambio de entorno.

Estoy utilizando la conversión de FONT a String por medio de

```
var cvt = new FontConverter();
string font  = cvt.ConvertToString(fontDialog.Font);
```

Luego grabo la variable font en un campo de la una base de datos para guardar la configuración
En mi máquina me graba lo siguiente : "Arial Narrow; 15,75pt; style=Bold"
Ya que tengo como separador de listas el ;

El problema es cuando quiero llevar el programa a una PC que tiene otro separador de listas al querer reconvertir desde la base da error.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para definir un separador antes de realizar la conversión para que no de error?

Saludos

Comment: El separador de lista viene del sistema Operativo Panel de control\Reloj y región\Región -> Configuración adicional Separador de Listas

Se puede acceder desde el programa
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator  pero es Read only

Comment: Y cual seria el codigo para convertir del string guardado en la base de datos al tipo de dato de la fuente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para convertir del tipo **Font** a **string** usa el **método ConvertToInvariantString**:

```
var cvt = new FontConverter();
string font = cvt.ConvertToInvariantString(fontDialog.Font);
```

Este método convierte la fuente a una representación de cadena invariante respecto al idioma.

Para el proceso inverso usa la sintaxis:

```
Font fuente = (Font)cvt.ConvertFromInvariantString("Arial, 12");
```

Aquí usas el **método ConvertFromInvariantString** para convertir un texto a la fuente que representa.

**Nota:** Como ejemplo yo uso el texto **"Arial, 12"**, pero ese dato tu debes extraerlo de la base de datos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias japv. En un rato pruebo toda la solución y te comento como me fue.

Comment: Fue de 10. Muchas GRacias